# .Net Best sql server to use

Tags: c#, .net, sql

HI, I'm trying to create a simple database for my C# .NET application.  It's easy enough to create a db and to run it locally, but I was wondering which is the best free one I should Use?  Furthermore, I would also like the application to be easily deployable on multiple PCs (each with their own local db instance).  What is the best tool for me to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite is very popular.

http://www.sqlite.org/

I would also add they have fantastic support across many platforms and uses:

http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html

Comment: +1 SQLite can be 'deployed' with your assembly by including the dll in the output directory.  It also is fairly fast and lightweight (compared to something like SQL Server Compact).  It is probably the most tested free portable database.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the latest SQL Server Compact Edition. It's designed to be embedded so you can easily deploy with the right files added to your install / copy setup.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0d2357ea-324f-46fd-88fc-7364c80e4fdb&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1):

[Postgres](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/) if you need this to be a serious solution, SQLite if it's a lightweight concern.

For my money, [Nhibernate suppor](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/DatabasessupportedbynHibernate)t is the important question.

Comment: I would add that many also use MySQL, although PostGRES is a very good one too.

Comment: I would add that MySQL would be somewhere in between Access and a POX file in my list of DB choices, but each to his own ;P

Answer (score 1):

If you're using .Net, why not use [SQL Server Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/)?

Comment: IMO, SQL Server Express is overkill for a single user on a single machine. It takes up precious memory, is always running in the background, and it also complicates the installation. SQL CE is a better choice me thinks...

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft answer is SQL Server CE (Compact Edition): http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx

There is an isntaller, but it can also be deployed just by including a few DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer should be the express edition of SQL Server :
http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/

Personally I just use microsoft access most of the time for simple stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Note that may users are suggesting SQL Server Compact Edition. It could be useful to know [the difference](http://www.microsoft.com/express/support/support-faq.aspx#SQLE). CE is much more limited, but easier to deploy. Sounds like CE is the better choice for your application.